# How do you assign an element to animate with Nativescript-Vue?

Tags: javascript, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Check this documentation:

https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/animation

I'm trying to add a class or ID of this element as `<Label>` to animate anything but I'm not sure what's is supposed to assign an element using `view` to take full control of any animation by calling animation methods directly with code instead of CSS animations in Vue template.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there's a good example of doing this from the Groceries sample app by Tiago Alves. I borrowed some of his code here, and you can animate like this:

Give your element a `ref`:

```
<AbsoluteLayout marginTop="-340" ref="logoContainer" class="logo-container">
    <Image translateY="0" src="res://seal" stretch="none"/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

and then grab that ref and animate it using the standard NativeScript Animation API:

```
this.$refs.logoContainer.nativeView
    .animate({
      translate: { x: 0, y: platformModule.isAndroid ? -70 : -50 },
      duration: 500,
      curve: enums.AnimationCurve.easeIn })
    .then(() => {
      this.state = 'main'
    })
```

Comment: Your original code gave me some errors, but I managed to edit some undefined objects and it worked.

Replace `platformModule.isAndroid` to some number like -50 just as `y: -50` and comment  `curve: enums.AnimationCurve.easeIn` it seems `enums` is undefined too, also comment `this.state = "main"` because this callback is optional.